# From tkinter.Entry.get save the entered data to text file

Tags: python, tkinter, exception

I am writing a small To Do App. The problem is that when I read the text from my Entry Widget. I can add it to a label but not write it to a text file. When I try the following error comes up:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\tomvo\PycharmProjects\To-Do-App\main.py", line 54, in addToDo
    toDoFile.write(f"\n{todo}")
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25cf' in position 3: character maps to <undefined>
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\\PycharmProjects\To-Do-App\main.py", line 54, in addToDo
    toDoFile.write(f"\n{todo}")
  File "C:Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25cf' in position 3: character maps to <undefined>
```

Can someone please help me to fix this?

Here is most of the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import json

class To_Do_App:
    font = ("Arial", 16, "bold")
    activeToDoRow = 2

    with open('settings.json', 'r') as JSONfile:
        data = JSONfile.read()

    data = json.loads(data)
    foreground = data['foreground']
    background = data['background']

    def __init__(self):
        self.mainWindow()

    def mainWindow(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("To-Do-App")
        self.root.configure(bg=self.background)

        self.menu = Menu(self.root, title="Menu")
        self.root.config(menu=self.menu)

        self.settingsMenu = Menu(self.menu, bg=self.background, fg=self.foreground)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=self.settingsMenu)
        self.settingsMenu.add_command(label="Theme", command=self.themeEditorWindow)

        self.title = Label(self.root, text="To-Do-App", bg=self.background, fg=self.foreground, font=self.font)
        self.title.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=25, padx=100)

        self.ToDoInput = Entry(self.root, bg=self.background, fg=self.foreground)
        self.ToDoInput.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=15)

        self.addToDoButton = Button(self.root, text="Add To-Do", bg=self.background, fg=self.foreground,
                                    command=self.addToDo)
        self.addToDoButton.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=15)

        self.loadOldToDos()

        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def addToDo(self):
        todo = self.ToDoInput.get()
        self.ToDoInput.delete(0 ,'end')
        todo = f' ●   {todo}'
        Label(self.root, text=todo, bg=self.background, fg=self.foreground).grid(row=self.activeToDoRow, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=5)
        self.activeToDoRow += 1
        
        with open("ToDos.txt", "a") as toDoFile:
            toDoFile.write(f"\n{todo}")

    def loadOldToDos(self):
        with open('ToDos.txt', 'r') as file:
            todos = file.read().splitlines()

        for todo in todos:
            todo = f' ●   {todo}'
            Label(self.root, text=todo, bg=self.background, fg=self.foreground).grid(row=self.activeToDoRow, column=0, columnspan=2,
                                                                         pady=5)
            self.activeToDoRow += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    To_Do_App()
```

This text is placeholder. I did not know what to explain more, but could not post because too much code. I hope this is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found my own problem. I wrote that I had to remove (todo = f' ● {todo}').
The letter ("●") was the problem